# String to Datetime can not convert - C#

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I found an example in MSDN for string to datetime conversion. But it doesn't work, fall into the catch(). Why this code block doesn't work?

```
DateTime dateValue;
      string dateString = "2/16/2008 12:15:12 PM";
      try {
         dateValue = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
         Console.WriteLine("'{0}' converted to {1}.", dateString, dateValue);
      }   
      catch (FormatException) {
         Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}'.", dateString);
      }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using whatever the current culture's idea of a date/time format is - and my guess is that you're in a culture where the day normally comes before the month.

If you know the format, I'd typically use the invariant culture and `TryParseExact` - definitely *don't* use `Parse` and a catch block; either use [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) or [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx). In this case:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 0, out dateValue))
{
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' converted to {1}.", dateString, dateValue);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}'.", dateString);
}
```

If you *don't* know the input format, but you know the culture to use, I'd just use `DateTime.TryParse` with the appropriate culture.

Comment: I didnt know that the culture is the effect on the error, Thank you so much, I got the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ParseExact` passing the appropriate format provider as in this example :

```
string dateString = "2/16/2008 12:15:12 PM"; 
    string format = "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt ";

    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format,
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```